# Finding index number

Tags: matlab

I have the following function, in which I'm attempting to receive a vector (`VectorX`) and a scalar (`thresholdY`). I want to check if 1) any element in `vectorX` is smaller than `thresholdY` and 2) if the smallest element of `vectorX` is smaller than 0.8 times the second smallest element of `vectorX`.

If both 1) and 2) are satisfied I then want to return the index of `vectorX` that we are currently on.

This is what I have currently (sorry it's a bit messy):

```
function [Z] = findCorr(vectorX, thresholdY)
Z = 0;

%A is our vector (for easier use)
A = vectorX;

%As is our sorted vector
As = sort(vectorX,'ascend');

%Am is A's min and Am2 is the second smallest value in A
Am = min(As);
Am2 = As(2);

%Ap is 0.8 of Am2
Ap = Am2 / 100 * 80;

%flag for breaking out of all loops
flag = 0;

for i = 1:A
    if A(i) < thresholdY && Am < Ap
        Z = find(A(:,i));
        flag = 1;
        break
    else
        Z = 0;
    end
    %use a flag to break out of loop
    if flag == 1
        break
    end
end

Z
```

Can someone tell me where I'm going wrong? The answer I'm expecting is 44, but I keep getting 0.

In case it's helpful, here's how I'm passing parameters to my function: `findCorr(SSDMatrix(1,:), 0.8)`